Question about Intermediate Value Theorem and its corollary in Mathematical Analysis I by Vladimir A. Zorich
In my class today we mentioned the IVTs and in the proof of the more general version of the theorem, that is, the version that says (as stated in Mathematical Analysis I by Vladimir A. Zorich)

If the function $\varphi$ is continuous on an open interval and
assumes values $\varphi(a) = A$ and $\varphi(b) = B$ at points $a$ and $b$, then for any number $C$ between $A$ and $B$, there is a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$ at which $\varphi(c) = C$

we used the IVT that I thought was a special case of the one that is quoted above (ibid):

Theorem 2. If a function that is continuous on a closed interval assumes values with different signs at the endpoints of the interval, then there is a point in the interval where it assumes the value $0$.

So this rubbed me the wrong way because it doesn't feel right to prove a more general statement with a statement that is (or can be?) its special case. And Zorich does the same in his textbook, which is, I believe, the origin of the proof we did in class. Nevertheless, I can't see anything wrong with the proof. I checked the IVT article on wikipedia and they seem agreeing with me on interpreting the $C=0$ case as a corollary. Also, two proofs of the general IVT are provided, where the latter of them somewhat resembles Zorich's proof:

Proof. The closed interval $I$ with endpoints $a$ and $b$ lies inside the open interval on which $\varphi$ is defined. Therefore the function $f(x) = \varphi(x) − C$ is defined and continuous on $I$. Since $f(a) \cdot f(b) = (A − C)(B − C) < 0$, Theorem 2 implies
that there is a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$ at which $f(c) = \varphi(c) − C = 0$.

So, is this just matter of personal taste, or is there some deeper insight hidden here? They're obviously not equivalent, so is this the case of where some earlier decisions we made dictate which one will imply the other, but where we could've made other decisions that would reverse the implication? And if yes, what was the decision? Admittedly, I didn't try to understand the mentioned proof from Wikipedia, but if someone here vouches that understanding it will clarify this issue for me, I'll do it.
Edit: For the sake of making the question more focused, let me restate my question more clearly: how is what is happening here valid and is my intuition warranted in any way? (note: at the time of this edit the question has already been answered.)
edit: I see one close vote because the question needs focus, so I’ll try to state my question more clearly hours when I get home (in a couple hours)

If theoram A is a generalization of theorem B, then of course thereom A can be viewed as corollary of theorem B. But it may nevertheless also be the case that - if you manage to prove theorem A without resorting to theorem B - one may find a simple proof of theorem B starting from theorem A. -- In fact, the very concept of proof by induction means that you prove $\forall n,P(n)$ by showing the special case $P(1)$ (and the induction step), which you may afterwards consider a corollary of the general statement

@HagenvonEitzen for induction I don’t have this odd distaste for it, because of the specific nature of natural numbers, so I’m fine with an eventual corollary being used in induction proofs. well, so far i understood corollary of Th. A as “consequence of Th. A”, meaning “Th. A implies the corollary”. consider statements: All powers of 2 are natural numbers and 2 is a natural number. id say that the second statement is a corollary of the first but the first statement is not a corollary of the second, whilst being a generalisation of the 2nd? can you help me understand where im wrong here.thanks

Now you are aware of the proof technique that starts with "Without loss of generality (WLOG) one may assume that $C=0$."

Think of this as a tool in your logic toolbox, a proof technique which you can call "proof by special cases": first prove a special case; then prove that the special case itself implies the general case.
Yes, this is a very easy example of proof by special cases.
And yes, without much trouble one can write the proof in the general case with the $A$'s and $B$'s and $C$'s. If the "proof by special cases" is not to your taste for this theorem, then the $A,B,C$ proof is fine.
But you might consider the possibility that this tool might turn out to be VERY useful in other places where a proof without it would be trouble indeed. One very fruitful mode of thought of a mathematician searching for an unknown proof goes like this:

I wonder if I can prove a special case........ OOOOHH! This special case implies the general case!!!!! So now all I have to do is prove the special case! [sits down to work...]


I see, thanks. I think I never encountered this technique, at least not in such a explicit form

To reinforce Lee's commentary, consider also Rolle's Theorem and the Mean Value Theorem. The former is a special case of the latter, and yet essentially every possible proof of the Mean Value Theorem reduces it to an application of Rolle's Theorem.
